# How to get working environment in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have some features that I only want shown when the website is run in dev mode (or in development environment). How can I programmatically determine what environment is currently being used?

E.g.

```
// $inDevEnvironment = ?
if ($inDevEnvironment) {

    // DEV feature here
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `sfConfig::get('sf_environment');`. It returns the string `dev` when in dev environment.

See this page for more info: http://sunzhen.blogspot.com/2012/02/symfony-get-working-environmentdevelopm.html